# Will x3 18650 batteries be enough for a nominal 12V vacuum cleaner?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am thinking to replace the old Ni MH Battery 12V pack of a B&D PD1200 portable vacuum cleaner with an x3 Li-ion batteries with an overcharge protection circuit. The new Li-ion pack is about 11.1V (3.7x3) instead of a nominal 12V.

So my question is, are 11.1V enough to powerup the vacuum cleaner or it will slow down its functionality? What are my options there?

Thank you.

Comment: do bear in mind the voltage will change from 12.6 at full charge to 10(ish) at minimum, a much larger relative voltage swing than with NiMH

Comment: @Neil_UK which means?

Comment: I think 4×LiFePO₄ cells would suit you better. Slightly more than 12V at 50% charge (so the vacuum will perform well), and nearly constant voltage, much like the NiMHs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using steady supply for a battery powered device is much more reliable. first, about the voltage range, the [wikipedia page on NiMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel%E2%80%93metal_hydride_battery#Discharge)  :

> A fully charged cell supplies an average 1.25 V/cell during discharge,
> declining to about 1.0–1.1 V/cell (further discharge may cause
> permanent damage in the case of multi-cell packs, due to polarity
> reversal). Under a light load (0.5 ampere), the starting voltage of a
> freshly charged AA NiMH cell in good condition is about 1.4 volts.

- [probably] 10x NiMH batteries : from 13v (fully charged) down to 10v, 12.5v most of the time
- 3 Li-Ion batteries : from 12.6v down to 9v. 11.1v most of the time.

so it doesn't seem much of a problem as the difference is marginal.

I have a B&D cordless drill which I changed the obsolete NiCad battery pack to Li-Ion. I used 2x2 batteries to produce 7.4v, and used a step up converter module and a big CAP and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Given that NiMH have a very stable voltage as they discharge, it’s quite likely that the motor runs directly from this supply, assuming that it will be more or less constant.  Running from a lower voltage will give less power.  This is more or less proportional to the square of the voltage so you’d expect 85% or normal power.  On the other hand, if the appliance uses a switch-mode supply to run the motor then you may see no degradation in power, although that would seem less likely because switch mode supplies cost money and 12v is a sensible voltage to use directly for a small motor.